# How to use pipes and redirects using os.execv(), if possible?

Tags: python

I'm getting a command and arguments from the user, parsing them, and passing them to `os.execvp()`, like so:

```
> ps -a -u -x

cmd = "ps"
args = ["-a", "-u", "-x"]
os.execvp(cmd, args)
```

The problem is that this doesn't work with pipes or redirects, so something like this wouldn't work:

```
> ps -a -u -x > output.txt

cmd = ps
args = ["-a", "-u", "-x", ">", "output.txt"]
os.execvp(cmd, args)
```

I understand that my problem is that `>` and `output.txt` are not arguments of `ps`, I just don't know the best way to solve this problem. I'm hoping I'm just missing the right method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `os.execv` we are at the low level of the OS.

To redirect the output, we need to replace the file descriptor no. 1 (stdout) before executing the command.

```
import os

STDOUT = 1

fdout = os.open('output.txt', os.O_WRONLY)
os.dup2(fdout, STDOUT)
os.execvp('ps', 'ps -a -u -x'.split())
# not reached
os._exit(127) # just for the case of execv failure
```

More work is required to connect two processes with a pipe. The pipe has two ends and must be created first. Then `fork` will duplicate the process. Each process must close one end of the pipe and redirect the other end to its stdin or stdout respectively.

```
import os

STDIN = 0 
STDOUT = 1 

pipein, pipeout = os.pipe()
if os.fork():
    # parent
    os.close(pipeout)
    os.dup2(pipein, STDIN)
    os.execlp('wc', '-l')
    # not reached
    os._exit(127)
else:
    # child
    os.close(pipein)
    os.dup2(pipeout, STDOUT)
    os.execvp('ps', 'ps -a -u -x'.split())
    # not reached
    os._exit(127)
```

These are just examples of concepts.