# How to pipe the output of execvp to variable in python

Tags: python, pipe, python-os

I have an assignment where we are making a shell for the Linux OS. And I have a lot of questions!

I was allowed to do it in python using some of the methods from the **os** library. The idea is that my program should communicate directly with the linux operating system calls.

So this include:

- Create
- Open
- Close
- Read
- Write
- Exit
- Pipe
- Exec
- Fork
- Dup2
- Wait

So far I made a working shell which can execute commands with **execvp** but I am having trouble with the piping stuff.

[I was reading this q/a and i felt that I almost understood what i have to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46598710/how-to-use-pipes-and-redirects-using-os-execv-if-possible)

I guess I have to use **Dup2** to write (and maybe read later). Also I am a little confused if I should use read() and write() at some point regarding to piping.

```py
from os import (
    execvp,
    wait,
    fork,
    close,
    pipe,
    dup2,
)
from os import _exit as kill

STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
STDERR = 2

CHILD = 0


def piping(cmd):
    reading, writing = pipe()
    pid = fork()
    if pid > CHILD:
        wait()
        close(writing)
        dup2(reading, STDIN)
        execvp(cmd[1][0], cmd[1])
        kill(127)
    elif pid == CHILD:
        close(reading)
        dup2(writing, STDOUT)
        execvp(cmd[0][0], cmd[0])
        kill(127)
    else:
        print('Command not found:', cmd)


piping([['ls', '-l', '/'], ['grep', 'var']])
```

If I run this code it works. But I don't understand some things:

- How can the execvp know that it gets extra arguments from the pipe?
- Why should i kill in the end and why is it 127?
- How is it possible to run the execvp inside the parent? Is this also possible in C?
- If I have a nested pipe eg: `ls -l / | grep var | xclip -selection clipboard` should I create a new fork then? (maybe some recursion)

It is not a part of the assignment to write to a file, but I might implement it as well later, when I get the piping to work.

- Should I use dup2 for that as well or maybe read/write

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: kill is just alias of _exit. The exec call should never return, the code assumes that if returns it means that the command doesnt exists so it exits with 127 status which is the status for no such file or directory. If you open your shell type ahshaudbajb, hit enter and then echo $?,  you should see 127. $? is the exit status for the last command

Comment: Okay thank you. I knew that it is an alias though, I made it up my self. :)

Comment: Actually in my real program I am running try: except OSError: so I never get the 127, bacuse it is catched evey time :)

Comment: exec(v)(p) knows nothing about pipes, it will just replace the current process by the one you passed by, it doesnt matter if is parent or not. Think about it as agents in matrix replacing anybody, the process incarnate the new program in its memory space and thats it

Comment: About piping, each side of a pipe will be a process, the lhs will share it's output with rhs input, this is what pipe + dup2 is doing. I dont remember dup2 semantics right now but I do remember that this is a common idiom in C, I guess is possible to do it with open and close file descriptors, Im not sure if you can control the FD numbers which is important for stdin and stdout. This was so common idiom that we have a syscall for it I would go with dup2

Comment: Now about shell, when you run some command in shell it forks, run the command in the child process, show its output and wait it to exit (join) and finally listem for input again, on your program youre overriding the parent so your shell will not be there anymore to listem for the child. Since the only way to spawn a new process is forking you will be doing this a lot. For 3 commands chained by pipes command you need to fork to get a child and then fork 3 times, one for each comand and tie the output to input streams and wait for everybody to finish

Comment: In dup2 you can control the FD numbers, it is the second parameter in the method. :-)

Comment: Oh thanks, It did a lot of this in 2012s :), but in C. It will fell just the same youre doing in python but with dangling pointers everywhere xD

Comment: I started with C as well :D

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will try to understand your comments :)

Comment: Should I make a new pipe() everytime i create a new fork()?

Comment: One for each |. If you have N commands chained by | you need N-1 pipes